# JavaScript While loop condition variable not getting updated

Tags: javascript, while-loop, increment

Why does the following logic not work?

**Warning**: The following starts an infinite loop when ou click Run code snippet.

```js
var i = 0;
var currentLocation = 1;

while(currentLocation !== 9){
    console.log(currentLocation);
    currentLocation += i;
    i++;
}
```

This goes into an infinite loop. But if we replace `currentLocation += i;` with `currentLocation++;`, it works as intended. Just curious as to why this happens.

Comment: "_Why does the following logic not work?_" Well, what is it _supposed_ to do?

Comment: Try adding a `console.log(currentLocation)`. Will it ever reach *exactly*  `9`?

Answer (score 7):

`currentLocation` starts out at 1.

In the loop:

On the first pass, it adds 0 to `currentLocation`, leaving it at 1.

On the second pass, it adds 1 to `currentLocation` making it 2.

On the third pass, it adds 2 to `currentLocation`, making it 4.

On the fourth pass, it adds 3 to `currentLocation`, making it 7.

On the fifth pass, it adds 4 to `currentLocation`, making it 11.

And so on.

As you can see, it's always `!== 9`.

---

This is the kind of thing that's best understood by stepping through the code statement by statement in the debugger built into your browser and/or IDE, watching the values of the variables as you go.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `currentLocation` never becomes equal to 9.

Iteration 1:

```
i = 0
currentLocation = 1 
1 + 0 = 1
```

Iteration 2:

```
i = 1
currentLocation = 1 
1 + 1 = 2
```

Iteration 2:

```
i = 2
currentLocation = 2 
2 + 2 = 4
```

Iteration 3:

```
i = 3
currentLocation = 4 
3 + 4 = 7
```

Iteration 4:

```
i = 4
currentLocation = 7 
7 + 4 = 11 // MORE than 9
```

Comment: Nice ninja edit. It would be better to take the time to write that detail **at first**, rather than editing it in afterward.

Comment: If you mean that I stole it from you or something, it's not. I just posted, then spent a time to edit, to only be surprised that there is already an answer with 6 votes lol

Comment: No, iI just mean it's best to take the time to answer completely in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Step through the process.

when you start

```
i = 0, currentLocation = 1
```

when you go through the first iteration

```
i = 1, currenttLocation = 1
```

when you go through the second iteration

```
i = 2, currentLocation = 2
```

on the third

```
i = 3, currentLocation = 4
```

on the fourth

```
i = 4 currentLocation = 7
```

on the fifth

```
i = 5 currentLocation = 11
```

since currentLocation will never exactly equal 9, the loop will never break